# How to generate random numbers in django

Tags: django-models

I want to generate automatic random numbers in a blank field while saving it in django.

---

**EDIT**

The random numbers must be unique.

Comment: do the random numbers need to be unique?

Comment: Ya it must be unique maz

Comment: I just updated my answer with a solution that should let you create unique random numbers. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 21):

EDIT: Changed solution to make random number unique and to use Django's make_random_password

function. Note the below assumes you are storing the random number in a field called

temp_password in a model UserProfile that is an extension of the User model.

```
random_number = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10, allowed_chars='123456789')

while User.objects.filter(userprofile__temp_password=random_number):
    random_number = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10, allowed_chars='123456789')
```

Also note that you can store the random code as a combination of letters and numbers as well. The

default value for allowed_chars is a string of letters and numbers minus a few that tend to cause

confusion among users (1, l, etc.)

More about Django's make_random_password function:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#manager-functions

OLD:

```
import random

n = random.randint(a,b) # returns a random integer
```

in the example above a <= n <= b

Many more types of random numbers in the random class:
http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: Your algorithm is exactly what I was looking for here. Not so much how you generate the randoms, but how you ensure their uniqueness. That's awesome, although I don't know about how efficient it is. If the User table get's really large things might get a little slow...but I don't see anyway around that.

Answer (score 2):

It is more a python thing than a django thing.

You can find all the information about Random class [here](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I've generated sucessfully

Answer (score 1):

Simply, I made a random number by random.randint in python. then as i need uniqe number, so i query this number to database, if this number is already exist, then i make again random by while loop.

```
random_num =  random.randint(2345678909800, 9923456789000)

uniqe_confirm = Order.objects.filter(order_id=random_num)

while uniqe_confirm:
    random_num =  random.randint(2345678909800, 9923456789000)
    if not Order.objects.filter(order_id=random_num):
        break
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea. This won't scale.