# generate unique id in each loop of for loop django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, frontend

I need to generate unique id in each loop instead of ````city-selected```

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
            <td class="input_td{% if field.errors %} error_td{% endif %}">
                <select name="city-select" id="city-select"></select>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td class="delete_formset_td"></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I generate it here?

I need some thing like this for ids:

**output**:

```
city-1
city-2
city-3
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random numbers in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353558/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-django)

Comment: no, first I need it in django-template in the front-end. second I need something like ````city-select-i```` but I don't know how should I generate that ID and use it in ````name```` and ````id```` sections. @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django template counter in nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870890/django-template-counter-in-nested-loops) Take a look at the second answer.

Comment: How can I use that generated text in id section? @IvanStarostin

Comment: `id="city-select-{{ variable }}"`

Comment: it worked. thanks @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`. It gives you the loop iteration as a number.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481499/django-iterate-number-in-for-loop-of-a-template).

```
{% for field in form %}

    <!-- your html -->

    city-{{ forloop.counter }}

{% endfor %}
```